# A linear bounded functional on $L^p[0,2\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have tried to find a solution the following problem but I did not come up with it. I want to find all values of $p\geq1$ for which the linear functional

$F[f]=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f(x)dx}{(1-sinx)^{1/6}}$

is bounded on $L^p[0,2\pi]$.

I will be glad if anyone can give me a hint!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Bounded linear functionals on $L^p$ correspond to members of $L^q$ where $1/p + 1/q = 1$ ($q=\infty$ in the case $p=1$).
 You need to determine for which $q$ you have
$(1-\sin(x))^{-1/6} \in L^q[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The linear functional is bounded if $|F(f)|\leq C||f||_p$. Here, We have $C=||(1-sinx)^{-1/6}||_q$. So, i need to find for which $q$ we have $(\int_0^{2\pi}|(1-sinx)^{-1/6}|^{q})^{1/q}<\infty$